# What VST do these kind of sounds come from?

Tags: sound-design, sound-libraries, replication, sounds

Ok, I'm trying to keep this as specific as I can.

I'm trying to write **New Age-y** music. Channels on YouTube like [Yellow Brick Cinema](https://www.youtube.com/user/YellowBrickCinema) (all their sounds) and [Mike Rowland](http://www.allmusic.com/artist/mike-rowland-mn0000494968) (his backing, not piano) and Aeoliah all have lovely, soft, background-y pad sounds - but I can't find where they get them from, all the 'pads' I have are FAR too 'lead-sound-in-trance'-y.

I know a "bit" about editing them - ADSR, Reverb, EQ etc. - but I can't find one sound that sounds as soft and warm as any of the above artists.  I know it's not supposed to be a discussion here - could anyone chuck an idea of where they get their sounds from at me? They're all essentially similar so they could all be using the same library - but what (affordably!)  I'm happy to have affordable near misses...

Current equipment. Sampletank Free, Esfera, P8, all the Korg Emulators (M1-Wavestation) Irish Acts Infinity, Orca, Rob Papen's Blue, Camel.... and others similar . I use a notation package cos I'm disabled, don't let that worry you, it just doesn't come with any of its own sounds so I have to do everything with downloads of some kind.)

If anyone goes 'AARGH!! They're sitting under his nose and he's not SEEING them!! then shove my head in a tutorial somewhere. I've probably just missed finding it!

Yellow Brick Cinema:

With Yellow Brick Cinema, their massive tracks are virtually all gorgeous pads - forget the lead sound like flute or anything - just the backing sounds, all the way through, for six hours - though I'm not expecting you to listen for that long!! Seriously, it's all of the backing sounds, not the backing sounds in any particular point.  If it turns out those particular sounds cost a year's salary, I'd be happy with anything that 'does the same job', because you can stick a decent lead sound on top and it still sounds sorta cool.

[Medwyn Goodall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medwyn_Goodall) (the pad at the start and in the middle of the instruments):

With Medwyn Goodall, I chose this track on purpose. His pad - he nearly always uses the same one in everything - starts right at the very beginning before any other sound kicks in. When the other sounds kick in, it goes into the background where it's fine if it disappears sometimes but if there's nothing else much happening it's still there sounding nice.

Mike Rowland, Angel Delight:

Again, like the others above, no particular timing, all the sounds all the way through. Yes the high one's strings and the low one's partially cello - but there's a ton of other sounds I THINK going on there to get the fullness. They're ALL the way through, no particular point.  I've got vaguely similar sounds but they're skinny compared to these even with no effects on them. Just pretend, any of you, someone was holding a gun to your head and yelling 'MAKE ME A PIECE LIKE THAT ONE!!' Where would you get the sounds from to make the piece with? If it's techniques like layering or whatever - I dunno - would you be able to tell me what they are/where the sounds come from he's doing it with/anything to help a noob out here?

I know it's up to me to write a decent piece with the sounds, but I'm feeling like a guy who wants to write flute music, doesn't realize it's a flute he's been listening to and only has a guitar right now anyway!

Yours respectfully,

Chris.

Comment: can you put links of he song in your post? Best !

Comment: Dear Jonhatan. Not all sites let you put links! Here they are. Yellow Brick Cinema: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNJDn8VcZ9Q  Medwyn Goodall (the pad at the start and in the middle of the instruments) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E2AmfV3CyI   Karunesh (again the pad in the middle of the instruments) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_bqt6kV0lU  Thanks very much in advance, whoever answers this! Chris.

Comment: With Yellow Brick Cinema, it's all the background sounds from the beginning - I'd love to know where to get anything similar from!  Chris.

Comment: can you add the links above directly into your post (click on edit). Also if the sound your searching have are of different types (leads, chords...) could create one post for each. And last thing can you put also the timing. Sorry I understand this is fastidious but this will be clearer for everyone. Best :)

Comment: Is the post OK now, and do you know any of the answers?

Comment: I don't have an answer for your problem, but if I was you I'll try to contact the channels/composers directly.

Comment: I did not have the time to really get into this yet. I hope I will have it during the weekend, but maybe I can give you some tips anyway. Since you mentioned that you're almost there, but your pads sound thin and skinny. Rich and warm pads often have a main oscillator and a second or even third one which are slighty detuned (only slightly!). This gives a richer feeling to it. Addiotnally, you could widen the range of your chords - like adding the lowest note again but 1 octave lower and much gentler, just to widen the base a bit. And you could also add a bit of LFO to make it less static

Comment: Dear Johnatan. Tried contacting the composers and asking them. It's like the pads are Their Own Special Secret and they're not saying anything! Tobi - thank you very, very much.  I'll practice doing that, and post my effort (HAH!!) to criticise - you won't hurt my feelings by criticising, anyone, you'll just be helping me learn something for once! Sorry I grumbled about your idea, Jonhatan, but the reluctance of these composers to tell anybody anything has been bugging me for years!  Chris. Everyone else who reads this - feel free to say anything at all, every little helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ultralinear that this sounds suspiciously like hardware. I was going to suggest a Kurzweil (PC3 for example)...These synths sound warm and musical whilst providing loads of subtle LFOs, modulations and envelopes. More than that though, the synth comes with lots of presets which are sculpted for the faders and controls on the synth itself, so that you can play it very expressively and intuitively, like a real musical instrument.

If you haven't got a spare £1000, A VST like OmniSphere or Absynth might float your boat. If you haven't got a spare few hundred quid, the *free* Crystal VST is very nice, but can be a bit of a learning curve.

Finally, ZynAddSubFX is also free (and can run on Linux if you're that way inclined) and is a bit of a masterpiece, but expect to spend a week or so getting your head round it. It sounds really, really good though.

Answer (score 1):

Medwyn Goodall has said (in interviews) that his entire studio set up at the time he recorded Medicine Woman was an 8-track tape recorder, a guitar, percussion and ONE Casio synth. He doesn't say which Casio synth but given the timing, think maybe a CZ (basically a Yamaha DX knockoff) or VZ series (known for nice sweeping pads) synth. If you're open to hardware, you can probably find something like this relatively cheap but I suspect there's a VST emulation of these out there as well...

Goodall's music still sounds pretty similar today. His current gear -- hardware and software -- can be found here, if you haven't already come across it: http://medwyngoodallmusic.co.uk/medwyn-goodall/studio-tour/

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about getting these sorts of sounds, I can strongly suggest a Roland JD-800. These are evolving pads, that have been boosted in the low end and soft clipped.

If I was asked to reproduce these sounds, it would be a JD-800 (I sold mine), through a Strymon Deco. The JD-800 has complex envelopes and modulation. The Deco produces this type of distortion.